# Smarty / PHP: foreach loop with three array

Tags: php, arrays, smarty

am making sitemap for my website which is multi language.

my current sitemap code looks like

```
{foreach from=$data.listings_en item=i}
<url>
<loc>{$i}</loc>
</url>
{/foreach}
```

it was only for english urls which was ok now am trying to add few other language with it but am not able to it as i do not how to pass three arrays to above foreach loop

three arrays i have

```
$data.listings_en
$data.listings_cn
$data.listings_ru
```

values in $data.listings_en

```
$listings_en[] = 'my link 1';

$data['listings_en']    = $listings_en;
```

what i want something like that

```
    {foreach from=$data.listings_en item=i}   // loop over three arrays all arrays have same size
    <url> 
    <loc>{$i}</loc>   // print url of listening_en 
 <loc>{$i}</loc>    // print url of listening_cn 
 <loc>{$i}</loc>  // print url of listening_ru 
    </url>
    {/foreach}
```

Comment: Do you really need all the languages in one template? Or one language per template?

Comment: How you are string values in `$data.listings_en`. Simple string or string in array?

Comment: @Sougata question updated  . values in $data.listings_en are string in array

Comment: Do - `$data['listings_en']    = 'my link 1';` & loop through `$data` only. I hope it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{foreach from=$data item=i} <li>{$i}</li>{/foreach}
```

Comment: $data have three arrays listings_ru , en and cn .... so how single $i will work ... i want three print in loop

Comment: {foreach from=$data item=i} <li>{$i.listings_en}</li><li>{$i.listings_cn}</li><li>{$i.listings_ru}</li>{/foreach}   it is not too clear because it depends on the next smarty what you asssignné $ smarty-> assign ( 'myArray', $ arr);